# Add edit link to a view for admins only

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view in Drupal 7 that uses the node's content for display. I would like to add an edit link to this view that only displays if you are an administrator viewing this page. I know how to do this if I am using fields as the display type but not when the display type is set to content. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [hook_field_attach_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7) to hide the field you've mentioned.

```
my_module_field_attach_view_alter(&$output, $context) {
  global $user;

  // check if the content is what you want to alter
  if ($context['entity_type'] != 'node'] || $content['view_mode']=='my_display') return;

  // only user with 'administrator' role can see
  $output['my_field']['#access'] = in_array('administrator', $user->roles));
}
```

[enter link description here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7)

Comment: This is the solution I implemented as it best address the requirements. However in my situation I implemented this code in the tpl file itself as that seemed to be the most appropriate place to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use field display to display the EDIT link, the link should actually only be shown to users with the appropriate permission to edit the content type.